# Do I need a transit visa for Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, filipino-citizens, iran

I'm from the Philippines, and I'm going to Kish Island, Iran. I'm flying via Dubai, staying in the airport, and then catching a connecting flight to Kish.

What are the requirements for me for a transit visa for Dubai?

Comment: Are you flying Emirates?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a visa to transit Dubai if you do not need to leave the international transit area of the airport. In that respect it is like most of the world's airports.

If you want to [leave the airport and visit Dubai](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/193455/can-i-leave-the-airport-when-transiting-through-dubai) during your layover, you will need to apply for a visa in advance. You can do this by visiting [Manage a booking](http://www.emirates.com/SessionHandler.aspx?pub=/english&pageurl=/MYB.aspx&section=MYB) on the Emirates web site and entering in your details. You need to get this visa in advance; your nationality is not eligible for [visa on arrival](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx).